# How do I make a button scroll to the part of the page?

Tags: android, button

I have a fragment that has a scroll view with a Relative layout as a parent holding different relative layouts. I also have a button at the top of my screen and what I'm trying to accomplish is, when the user clicks on a button it'll move the screen to a part of the page. For example the button#2 when clicked scrolls down to the part of the page where relative layout #2 is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,
Use this code to get the location of your layout to which you want to scroll to.

```
int[] locations = getViewLocations(yourcustomview);
int x = locations[0]; // x position of left
int y = locations[1]; // y position of top
```

When you get this value, 
call `yourparentscrollview.srcollTo(x,y);`